# Bootstrap 3 fallback for Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, fallback

Yesterday all my Bootstrap 3.3.x sites didn't load the js/css files from MaxCdn (in The Netherlands) so today I searched for a fallback. JQuery is easy, but for Bootstrap CSS I only find examples which put the local css file as the first line in the head. The following code is what I have so far to put the local Bootstrap CSS on the correct place in case of a fallback.

In the head:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>CDN fallback</title>
<link id="cssbs" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/ABC_bootstrap.min.css">
<link id="csscu" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="author" content="Foo">
```

At the end of body:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/ABC_jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="lib/jquery-1.11.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/ABC_bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
if(typeof($.fn.modal) === 'undefined'){
  document.write('<script src="lib/bootstrap-3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>')
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bodyColor = $('body').css('color');
  var localCss  = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap-3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">';
  if(bodyColor != 'rgb(51, 51, 51)'){
    $("#cssbs").replaceWith(localCss);
  }
});
</script>
```

My question: What about perormance? Any suggestion for a better fallback?

Note: for testing I typed ABC in the CDN filename.

Thanks, Ronald

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do fallback loads for CDNs is to have the scripts/stylesheets loaded asynchronously with a timeout, that way if the CDN is taking too long to respond (as it may be down), you load a replacement file within a reasonable amount of time.  To do this, you can implement a function such as `fallbackLoad` below and have it within the `HEAD` portion of your HTML page.

```
function fallbackLoad(urls, callback, timeout) {
    var url = urls.shift()
    timeout = timeout || undefined;
    callback = callback || function() {};
    var error = (function(urls, callback) {
        return function() {
            if (urls.length == 0) {
                console.error('Failed to fallback, all urls down');
            } else {
                makeRequest(urls.shift(), callback, error);
            }
         };
    })(urls, callback);
    return makeRequest(url, callback, error);
}
```

Then define your `makeRequest` function as

```
function makeRequest(url, success, error, timeout) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (timeout) {
        xhr.ontimeout = error;
    }
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) { 
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                success(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                error();
            }
         }
    };
    xhr.open("GET", url, true /* async */);
    if (timeout) xhr.timeout = timeout;
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

Now you can call `fallbackLoad` in the `HEAD` of your script without it holding up the loading of your page.  You can call it as

```
fallbackLoad([
    '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/ABC_jquery.min.js',
    'lib/jquery-1.11.1/jquery.min.js'
], function(response) {
    ....
}, 500 /* ms */);
```